# How to download file stored in Firebase Fire Storage through a firebase cloud function?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have multiple cloud functions deployed which are acting as backend to my app(s), where I used firedb and firestorage, however I am stuck at downloading files through stored file in fire storage, Can anyone help me with NodeJS samples to download a file (stored in fire storage) through cloud functions.

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you are looking for, but here is the docs on how to download file from Cloud Storage with Cloud Functions : https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events#download_transform_and_upload_a_file